# JasperReport - Using DynamicJasper after having a lot of JRXML reports built

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

**JasperReport - Using DynamicJasper after having a lot of JRXML reports built**

**Problem Overview**

Currently my java software uses compiled .jrxml files to generate reports. However, the users are complaining that they want to customize the reports. Which is basically  So I found out about DynamicJasper. The problem is that the ready-to-use .jasper reports that I previously Built has their own layout which I ended up adjusting, inserting image placeholders for logos that are sent via parameters.

---

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to either copy the style or re-use these previously built report layouts in a simple way?

---

As far as I remember, I built those reports using the Jasper template called Cherry . And For some I used landscape and for others I used portrait type.

---

I Dont think this question is a duplicate due to the constraints of the problem itself: I cant rebuild every report to be DynamicJasper nor I can change the layour aggressively.

**References**

[How to use jrxml file as design template in DynamicJasper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050758/how-to-use-jrxml-file-as-design-template-in-dynamicjasper)

[How to get same styles in DynamicReports and JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38639984/how-to-get-same-styles-in-dynamicreports-and-jasperreports)

Comment: Quite interesting how you vote to close the question but dont even comment on it.

Comment: I ended up creating the templates in Java code instead. I don't think there is a 'simple way' as what you're asking is about integrating the two. Check http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/xref-test/ar/com/fdvs/dj/test/TemplateFileReportTest.html for ways of doing this, surely integrating will be just as time consuming as building them to be properly dynamic

Comment: There is another way That I found out. I will post an answer later today. But thanks for the comment :)

Comment: I would be very interested in that cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to answer my own question, here's a recipe.

**1º You take your jrxml and clean it according to :**
http://dynamicjasper.com/2010/10/06/how-to-use-custom-jrxml-templates/

Which basically **requires:**

- The template must not have groups, DynamicJAsper will create them if
  necessary.
- The detail band must be empty: DynamicJasper will work in the detail 
  band, any previously existing element will be deleted.
- One template per page size and orientation will be needed: This is
  because DJ knows how to arrange the element he creates, but not the
  existing ones.

**2º You call setTemplateFile method:**

```
 public DynamicReportBuilder setTemplateFile(String path,
                                                         boolean importFields,
                                                         boolean importVariables,
                                                         boolean importParameters,
                                                         boolean importDatasets)
```

With the required boolean flags. Those boolean flags will allow you to load or not load the parameters,fields,variables and dataset that you set on your jrxml.

And below I attach a mock example. However, you are going to need your own jrxml file to test.

```
public class TestReport {

    protected static JasperPrint jp;
    protected static JasperReport jr;
    protected static Map params = new HashMap();
    protected static DynamicReport dr;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, ColumnBuilderException, ClassNotFoundException {

        TestReport t = new TestReport();
        t.createReport();

    }

    public void createReport() throws SQLException, ColumnBuilderException, ClassNotFoundException {

        ArrayList<Fruit> createMockDataset = createMockDataset();

        Style titleStyle = new Style();
        titleStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
        titleStyle.setFont(Font.ARIAL_SMALL_BOLD);

        Style dataStyle = new Style();
        dataStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
        dataStyle.setFont(Font.ARIAL_SMALL);
        dataStyle.setBlankWhenNull(true);

        final List items = SortUtils.sortCollection(createMockDataset, Arrays.asList(new String[]{"name", "description"}));

        FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
        drb.setTemplateFile("templatePortrait.jrxml", true, true, true, true);
        drb.addColumn("name", "name", String.class.getName(), 30, dataStyle)
                .addColumn("description", "description", String.class.getName(), 50, dataStyle)
                .setTitle("Report")
                .setSubtitle("")
                .setPrintBackgroundOnOddRows(true)
                .setUseFullPageWidth(true);



        DynamicReport dynamicReport = drb.build();

        dynamicReport.setTitleStyle(titleStyle);

        HashMap parametros = new HashMap();
        parametros.put("dataRelatorio", MyTools.getDataPorExtenso());

        doReport(dynamicReport, items, parametros);
    }

    public void doReport(final DynamicReport _report, final Collection _data, HashMap parametros) {
        try {
            JRDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(_data);

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(_report, new ClassicLayoutManager(), beanCollectionDataSource, parametros);

            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public ArrayList<Fruit> createMockDataset() {
        ArrayList<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>();

        Fruit f1 = new Fruit();
        f1.name = "Apple X1";
        f1.description = "Yummy yummy apple for the stackoverflow readers 1";

        Fruit f2 = new Fruit();
        f2.name = "Apple Ag";
        f2.description = "Yummy yummy apple for the stackoverflow readers 2";

        Fruit f3 = new Fruit();
        f3.name = "Apple Mn";
        f3.description = "Yummy yummy apple for the stackoverflow readers 3";

        Fruit f4 = new Fruit();
        f4.name = "Apple O2";
        f4.description = "Yummy yummy apple for the stackoverflow readers 4";

        //Evaluations for f1
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Evaluation e = new Evaluation();
            e.id = i;
            e.score = Math.random() * 10;
            f1.evaluations.add(e);
        }

        //evaluations for f4
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Evaluation e = new Evaluation();
            e.id = i;
            e.score = Math.random() * 10;
            f4.evaluations.add(e);
        }

        fruits.add(f1);
        fruits.add(f2);
        fruits.add(f3);
        fruits.add(f4);

        return fruits;

    }

    public class Fruit {

        public String name;
        public String description;
        public ArrayList<Evaluation> evaluations = new ArrayList<Evaluation>();

        public Fruit() {

        }

        public Fruit(String name, String description) {
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public ArrayList<Evaluation> getEvaluations() {
            return evaluations;
        }

        public void setEvaluations(ArrayList<Evaluation> evaluations) {
            this.evaluations = evaluations;
        }

    }

    public class Evaluation {

        public int id;
        public double score;

        public Evaluation() {

        }

        public Evaluation(int id, double score) {
            this.id = id;
            this.score = score;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public double getScore() {
            return score;
        }

        public void setScore(double score) {
            this.score = score;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for this! any ideas on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754683/how-to-get-total-price-with-whole-column-not-each-entry-and-group-title-in-d)